# Digg Style Form Validation with Hints with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am looking for a form validation utility with cool effects similar to the Digg's Registration Page. I have been searching for a tutorial/code but could not find the perfect one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking I think would be something along the lines of the [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have already checked it. I am looking for a better solution which can work exactly as the example I have provided.

Comment: Or, if there is a way to get this sample jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk done without tables, that will also do.

Comment: The plugin can be used without tables. You will need to modify the `errorContainer` option.

Comment: Got It, but small problem. I used a div and span combination to show the form element and error. Div contains both form element and Span. I made a setting to write the error message to Span, but when I placed this in my main page, the error message is going to next line. It worked fine in the test page without any additional content.

Comment: This issue is also resolved. Now it shows in the same line. There was a conflict in the css.